# PHP multidimensional array and while i++

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, html-table

So I'm having a problem creating the table with "names". I only got two results instead of 4. Here is my multidimensional array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 1
            [name] => Test_name_1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 6
            [name] => Test_name_2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 22
            [name] => Test_name_3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 23
            [name] => Test_name_4
        )

)
```

Then I want to create table with `$i=1;` and until 47. So my code here is:

```php
$i=1;
while ($i<=47){
 foreach($array as $test){
    echo '<tr>';      

    if ($test['start']==$i){
      echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;"><b>'.$test['name'].'</b> </td>';
    }else{
      echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">blank </td>';
    }
    echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">'.$i.' </td>';
    $i++;
    echo '<tr>';
  };

}
```

The result I receive only displays 2 names instead of 4 in the array:

[image: my table]

Why are **Test_name_3** and **Test_name_4** excluded from my result?

Comment: It looks like you’re never closing your <tr> tag. Try

         $i++;
        echo '</tr>';

Comment: Thanks, i've corrected the closing <tr> tag , but the result is still the same.

Strange thing is if i edit the "Test_name_1" to start position "2", it will also not show in the table.

Comment: I must confess, I find the way you’ve structured your code a bit difficult to read.  You seem to be counting up to 47 in your while loop (which is good) but then doing your table row (tr) 4 times each iteration inside your foreach loop.  I think you want to move the <tr> and closing </tr> outside to the while loop. Also I think you want to move your second <td> set outside to your while loop as well.  That way you’re doing each of those once per iteration instead of 4 times per iteration. Also, your i++ needs to be moved out to your while loop.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried, but the results are the same. I added <tr> outside the loop, but if i add the second <tr> outside the loop, my table has 4 <td> tags.

Comment: If I were writing it, the only things inside the foreach loop would be the if/else statement. Actually, if I were writing it I would extract the foreach entirely to a function, so I only had one loop to worry about.  I guess I’m trying to find a polite way to say that if you had your code structured a little differently, it would be easier for you to debug it.  Nesting a loop inside a loop always makes things hard to understand, and you’ve got lots of things in the wrong parts of the wrong loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following logic might help you solve your issue:

```
<?php
$arr = [
    ['start' => 1, 'name' => 'Test_name_1'], ['start' => 6, 'name' => 'Test_name_2'],
    ['start' => 22, 'name' => 'Test_name_3'], ['start' => 23, 'name' => 'Test_name_4'],

];

$hit = false;
echo '<table>';
for($i = 1; $i <= 47; $i++) {
echo '<tr>';
    foreach($arr as $record) {
        if($record['start'] == $i) {
            $hit = true;
            echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;"><b>' . $record['name'] . '</b> </td>';
            echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">' . $i . ' </td>';
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!$hit) {
        echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">blank </td>';
        echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">' . $i . ' </td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
    $hit = false;
}
echo '</table>';
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/gH3YV)

Answer (score 0):

```php
$i = 1;
while ($i <= 47) {
    foreach ($array as $test) {
        echo '<tr>';

        if ($test['start'] == $i) {
            echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;"><b>' . $test['name'] . '</b> </td>';
        } else {
            echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">blank </td>';
        }
        echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">' . $i . ' </td>';
        echo '<tr>';
    };
    $i++;
}
```

Take $i++ outside of foreach loop!!!

Comment: If i add $i++ outside the loop, then the second row get's multiplayed  [link](https://imgur.com/QlVs791)

Answer (score 0):

this might solve your problem with while loop

```
                $array = [
                    ['start' => 1, 'name' => 'Test_name_1'], ['start' => 6, 'name' => 'Test_name_2'],
                    ['start' => 22, 'name' => 'Test_name_3'], ['start' => 23, 'name' => 'Test_name_4'],

                ];
                echo '<table>';
                $i=1;
                while ($i<=47){
                $count=0;
                foreach($array as $test){
                
                    if (((int)$test['start'])==$i){
                        echo '<tr>'; 
                    echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;"> 
                    <b>'.$test['name'].'</b> </td>';
                    echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">'.$i.' </td>';
                    echo '</tr>'; 
                    }else{
                        $count=$count+1;
                        if( $count==count($array))
                        {
                        echo '<tr>'; 
                    echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">blank </td>';
                    echo '<td align="center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">'.$i.' </td>';
                    echo '</tr>'; }
                }
                }
                $count=0;
                $i++;
                }
                echo '</table>';
```

Comment: same results as mine. I also send the <tr> tag outside the loop.